# Change Python version for pip-compile

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

When I run pip-compile, part of the generated file is this:

```
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with python 3.8
```

I suppose this is happening because I cloned a project that contained a setup.py at one point that specified Python 3.8. However, I changed a lot of the code and removed the setup.py so that no more references to Python 3.8 are present in my code, and I'm actually using Python 3.9 now. Still, even when I've activated my Python 3.9 venv in the same shell before calling, `pip-compile`, the line containing Python 3.8 ends up in the requirements file. How can I reconfigure pip-compile to output 3.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip-compile has the python version in his file

1./ Which pip-compile do you use

> which pip-compile

```
/usr/local/bin/pip-compile
```

2./ Which python version use pip-comple

> head -1 /usr/local/bin/pip-compile

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/pip-tools/6.12.1/libexec/bin/python3.11
```

3./ You know find the version used with pip-compile

In my case python3.11

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Or, at least, for my particular case.

Use `where pip-compile` to find and edit your pip-compile.

Make sure the version of python it's referring to is the same as what you get from `where python`.

Answer (score -1):

Go and edit your environment variable in that it targets python 3.9 or reinstall python 3.9 and check the add to path checkbox.

Comment: What about virtual environments?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer; however, this happens when I've already activated my 3.9 venv.

Comment: And how exactly do you reinstall Python 3.9? Which checkbox? Do you mean to use a GUI installer?

Comment: yah GUI, which os are you using